# How to get related object fields without the id in a query

Tags: apex, getter

I am working through a class that runs on before insert on the OpportunityLineItem object.

Basically, I create a key on the OLI record, search for an existing custom object (Responsible Party) record, if there is no matching key I create a new record and then finally I match and assign the Responsible Party into a lookup field on the OLI. This works in the sandbox where I can populate existing party records or newly created party records.

Where I am stuck is I want to populate the Account Owner into a user lookup field and the Account Owner's Name into a text field. in my method getResParty. I can get the Account Id from a string set but I can't figure out how to query for the account value without doing a query in a for loop or using a get wit the id.

When I try to compile this code I get the error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: get(String)

on the line

```
newResParty.User__c = get(strKey.left(18)).OwnerId;
```

Where am I going wrong?

```
public without sharing class NPD_Responsible_Party_Locator
{

public static void filterInsert(List<OpportunityLineItem> newList)
{
    List<OpportunityLineItem> olis = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
    Set<String> olikeys = new Set<String>();
    Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> prodIds = new Set<Id>();

    // Create a set of all the unique Opp Ids that we need to query for
    for(OpportunityLineItem oliO : newList)
        oppIds.add(oliO.OpportunityId);

    // Create a map so that Opportunity is locatable by its Id (key)
    Map<Id, Opportunity> oppsMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>(
        [SELECT Id, Account.OwnerId, AccountId FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :oppIds]);

    // Create a set of all the unique Product Ids that we need to query for
    for(OpportunityLineItem oliP : newList)
        prodIds.add(oliP.Product2Id);

    // Create a map so that the Product is locatable by its Id (key)
    Map<Id, Product2> prodsMap = new Map<Id, Product2>(
        [SELECT Id, Formula_LOB__c, Practice__c, Practice__r.Key_Type__c FROM Product2 WHERE Id IN :prodIds]);

    // On Insert we add to all products
    for(OpportunityLineItem oppyLine : newList)
    {
        olikeys.add(oppsMap.get(oppyLine.OpportunityId).AccountId + '-' + prodsMap.get(oppyLine.Product2Id).Practice__c);
        olis.add(oppyLine);
    }

    Map<String, Responsible_Party__c> rmap = getResParty(olikeys);
    updateOLI(rmap, olis, oppsMap, prodsMap);
}

public static Map<String, Responsible_Party__c> getResParty(Set<String> olikeys)
{
    Map<String, Responsible_Party__c> rmap = new Map<String, Responsible_Party__c>();

    for(Responsible_Party__c r : [SELECT    Id,
                                            Name,
                                            User__c,
                                            Sector__c,
                                            Key__c
                                  FROM      Responsible_Party__c
                                  WHERE     Key__c IN : olikeys])
    {
        rmap.put(r.Key__c, r);
    }

    //if record does not exists then create the record here
    List<Responsible_Party__c> rlst = new List<Responsible_Party__c>();
    Set<String> newKeySet = new Set<String>(); //capture Key__c for which records to be created. It will help to fetch newly created records.

    for(String strKey : olikeys)
    {
        if(!rmap.containsKey(strKey))
        {
            Responsible_Party__c newResParty = new Responsible_Party__c();
            newResParty.Key__c = strKey;
            newResParty.Name = 'Workflow Field Update';
            newResParty.Key_Type__c = 'Account - Practice';
            newResParty.Practice__c = strKey.right(18);
            newResParty.User__c = get(strKey.left(18)).OwnerId;
            newResParty.Team_Name__c = get(strKey.left(18)).Owner.Name;
            newResParty.Account__c = strKey.left(18);

            rlst.add(newResParty);
            newKeySet.add(strKey);
        }
    }
    insert rlst;

    //retrieve newly created values and add this to the map
    for(Responsible_Party__c r : [SELECT    Id,
                                            Name,
                                            User__c,
                                            Sector__c,
                                            Key__c
                                  FROM      Responsible_Party__c
                                  WHERE     Key__c IN : newKeySet])
    {
        rmap.put(r.Key__c, r);
    }
    return rmap;
}

public static void updateOLI(Map<String, Responsible_Party__c> rmap, List<OpportunityLineItem> olis, Map<Id, Opportunity> oppsMap, Map<Id, Product2> prodsMap)
{
    Responsible_Party__c r = new Responsible_Party__c();

    for(OpportunityLineItem o : olis)
    {
        r = rmap.get(oppsMap.get(o.OpportunityId).AccountId + '-' + prodsMap.get(o.Product2Id).Practice__c);

        if(r != null)
        {
            o.Responsible_Party__c = r.Id;
        }
        else{
            o.Responsible_Party__c = null;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You seem to be using `get` like a function, but it needs an instance of a map to be called from, which you use elsewhere in this code (`rmap.get(...)`). You should identify what map you want to call `get` on, and start there.

Comment: You can also skip some space when making maps of sObjects by calling the soql like this: `Map<Id, sObject> someMap = new Map<Id, sObject>([SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id IN :someIds]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find my comments in the code.

Step 1: Retrieve Account Information from this SOQL

```
Map<Id, Opportunity> oppsMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>(
        [SELECT Id, Account.OwnerId, Account.Owner.Name , AccountId FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :oppIds]);
```

Step 2: Then store them into `oliAccountMap` like this:

```
// On Insert we add to all products
    for(OpportunityLineItem oppyLine : newList)
    {
        olikeys.add(oppsMap.get(oppyLine.OpportunityId).AccountId + '-' + prodsMap.get(oppyLine.Product2Id).Practice__c);
        //put information respective to OLI.
        oliAccountMap.put(oppyLine.Id, oppsMap.get(oppyLine.OpportunityId).Account.OwnerId + '-' + oppsMap.get(oppyLine.OpportunityId).Account.Owner.Name);
        olis.add(oppyLine);
    }
```

Step 3: Pass `oliAccountMap` as a parameter of `getResParty` method.

Step 4: Then retrieve elements from `oliAccountMap`

```
String[] strAccountInfo = oliAccountMap.get(strKey).split('-');

 newResParty.User__c = strAccountInfo[0];  //Account's OwnerId
 newResParty.Team_Name__c = strAccountInfo[1]; //Account's Owner Name
```

Entire code

```
public without sharing class NPD_Responsible_Party_Locator
{

public static void filterInsert(List<OpportunityLineItem> newList)
{
    List<OpportunityLineItem> olis = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
    Set<String> olikeys = new Set<String>();
    Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> prodIds = new Set<Id>();

    Map<String, String> oliAccountMap = new Map<String, String>();

    // Create a set of all the unique Opp Ids that we need to query for
    for(OpportunityLineItem oliO : newList)
        oppIds.add(oliO.OpportunityId);

    // Create a map so that Opportunity is locatable by its Id (key)
    Map<Id, Opportunity> oppsMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>(
        [SELECT Id, Account.OwnerId, Account.Owner.Name , AccountId FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :oppIds]);


    // Create a set of all the unique Product Ids that we need to query for
    for(OpportunityLineItem oliP : newList)
        prodIds.add(oliP.Product2Id);

    // Create a map so that the Product is locatable by its Id (key)
    Map<Id, Product2> prodsMap = new Map<Id, Product2>(
        [SELECT Id, Formula_LOB__c, Practice__c, Practice__r.Key_Type__c FROM Product2 WHERE Id IN :prodIds]);

    // On Insert we add to all products
    for(OpportunityLineItem oppyLine : newList)
    {
        olikeys.add(oppsMap.get(oppyLine.OpportunityId).AccountId + '-' + prodsMap.get(oppyLine.Product2Id).Practice__c);
        //put information respective to OLI.
        oliAccountMap.put(oppyLine.Id, oppsMap.get(oppyLine.OpportunityId).Account.OwnerId + '-' + oppsMap.get(oppyLine.OpportunityId).Account.Owner.Name);
        olis.add(oppyLine);
    }

    Map<String, Responsible_Party__c> rmap = getResParty(olikeys,oliAccountMap);
    updateOLI(rmap, olis, oppsMap, prodsMap);
}

public static Map<String, Responsible_Party__c> getResParty(Set<String> olikeys, Map<String, String> oliAccountMap)
{
    Map<String, Responsible_Party__c> rmap = new Map<String, Responsible_Party__c>();

    for(Responsible_Party__c r : [SELECT    Id,
                                            Name,
                                            User__c,
                                            Sector__c,
                                            Key__c,
                                            OwnerId,
                                            Owner.Name,
                                  FROM      Responsible_Party__c
                                  WHERE     Key__c IN : olikeys])
    {
        rmap.put(r.Key__c, r);
    }

    //if record does not exists then create the record here
    List<Responsible_Party__c> rlst = new List<Responsible_Party__c>();
    Set<String> newKeySet = new Set<String>(); //capture Key__c for which records to be created. It will help to fetch newly created records.

    for(String strKey : olikeys)
    {
        if(!rmap.containsKey(strKey))
        {
            Responsible_Party__c newResParty = new Responsible_Party__c();
            newResParty.Key__c = strKey;
            newResParty.Name = 'Workflow Field Update';
            newResParty.Key_Type__c = 'Account - Practice';
            newResParty.Practice__c = strKey.right(18);
            String[] strAccountInfo = oliAccountMap.get(strKey).split('-');

            newResParty.User__c = strAccountInfo[0];  //Account's OwnerId
            newResParty.Team_Name__c = strAccountInfo[1]; //Account's Owner Name
            newResParty.Account__c = strKey.left(18);

            rlst.add(newResParty);
            newKeySet.add(strKey);
        }
    }
    insert rlst;

    //retrieve newly created values and add this to the map
    for(Responsible_Party__c r : [SELECT    Id,
                                            Name,
                                            User__c,
                                            Sector__c,
                                            Key__c
                                  FROM      Responsible_Party__c
                                  WHERE     Key__c IN : newKeySet])
    {
        rmap.put(r.Key__c, r);
    }
    return rmap;
}

public static void updateOLI(Map<String, Responsible_Party__c> rmap, List<OpportunityLineItem> olis, Map<Id, Opportunity> oppsMap, Map<Id, Product2> prodsMap)
{
    Responsible_Party__c r = new Responsible_Party__c();

    for(OpportunityLineItem o : olis)
    {
        r = rmap.get(oppsMap.get(o.OpportunityId).AccountId + '-' + prodsMap.get(o.Product2Id).Practice__c);

        if(r != null)
        {
            o.Responsible_Party__c = r.Id;
        }
        else{
            o.Responsible_Party__c = null;
        }
    }
}
}
```